Error with MeanAbsolutePercentageError() in tensorflow model with AdamW algorithm
I was trying to find the optimum number of nodes for 2 hidden layers in an artificial neural network. I wanted to use MeanAbsolutePercentageError to evaluate the accuracy of my model. This is the subsection of code with an error:
This is my code:
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.losses import MeanAbsoluteError
from tensorflow.keras.utils import set_random_seed
from tensorflow.keras.losses import MeanAbsolutePercentageError
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import AdamW
set_random_seed(777)

RESULTS = []
for A in range(1, 8):
  for B in range(1, 8):

    set_random_seed(777)
    MODEL = Sequential(layers=[Dense(units=A , activation="elu" , input_shape=[TRAIN_X.columns.size]),
                                        Dense(units=B , activation="elu") ,
                                        Dense(units=1)])
    MODEL.compile( optimizer=AdamW() ,
                  loss=MeanAbsolutePercentageError() )
    MODEL.fit(  TRAIN_X/10 , TRAIN_Y/10 ,
                          validation_data=[ TEST_X / 10 , TEST_Y / 10 ] , epochs=300 )
    PREDICTIONS = MODEL.predict( TEST_X / 10 ) * 10
    C = MeanAbsolutePercentageError( PREDICTIONS , TEST_Y )
    RESULTS.append([A, B, C])

I was expecting my results to be in an arrary of [A,B,C] format meaning A = # nodes in first hidden layer, B = # nodes in the second hidden layer, C = Mean absolute percentage error. However, I got this error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-59489aa7b7de> in <cell line: 10>()
     20                           validation_data=[ TEST_X / 10 , TEST_Y / 10 ] , epochs=300 )
     21     PREDICTIONS = MODEL.predict( TEST_X / 10 ) * 10
---> 22     C = MeanAbsolutePercentageError( PREDICTIONS , TEST_Y )
     23     RESULTS.append([A, B, C])

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/utils/losses_utils.py in validate(cls, key)
     85     @classmethod
     86     def validate(cls, key):
---> 87         if key not in cls.all():
     88             raise ValueError(
     89                 f'Invalid Reduction Key: {key}. Expected keys are "{cls.all()}"'

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()


MeanAbsolutePercentageError() is a class that you have to initiate before calling. Try MeanAbsolutePercentageError()( PREDICTIONS , TEST_Y ). First () is constructing the class, second (...) is calling it. You can also use model.evaluate() instead of model.predict() to get the error, when you use it in model.compile.
